# subprocessのcheck_callでディレクトリサイズを出力結果として保持したい

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

初めて質問させて頂きます。宜しくお願い致します。

subprocessモジュールを使用し、指定したディレクトリの 
データサイズを取得するshellを実行し、結果を判定する処理を作成しております。

取得するディレクトリ( **/var/hoge** とします。)のデータサイズの取得は 
Linuxのduコマンドを用いて取得しようと考えております。

その際に、subprocess.check_output()を用いて 
引数でコマンドを実行し、出力結果を取得して判定したいのですが

①duコマンドの出力結果をうまく整形したい 
（試行錯誤し、一応できましたが、このやり方しかないのでしょうか）

②バイト文字列のキャストは int(ret) のような書き方しかないでしょうか。

が知りたいです。

実行環境 
Linux OS: Laspbian kernel 4.1 
Python: 2.7.9

※ /var/hoge のサイズは 4096byteとした場合 
下記でコマンドを実行した際は

```
4096    /var/hoge
```

となります。

4096だけを取り出し 
指定したサイズと比較したいとした場合。

作成したコード

```
import subprocess

def testcall():
    reta = []
    cmd = "du -b /var/hoge"
    ret = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
    reta = ret.split()
    size = 1024
    if int(reta[0]) >= int(size) :
        print('DirSize:[%d] ' % int(reta[0]) )
    return
```

思っていること 
・リストretaを介さなければいけないのか。 
・リストretaは毎回キャストしなければいけない？

言葉足らずであったばあい、申し訳御座いません。 
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/29477

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下のものでいかがですか? 基本的には御提示になったようにすると思います．あとsizeは1024を代入した時点で`int`なのでcastする必要はないです．文字列から`int`にcastするのは`int()`でいいです．

```
import subprocess

def testcall():
    cmd = "du -b /var/hoge"
    dsize = int(subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).split()[0])
    size = 1024
    if dsize >= size :
        print('DirSize:[%d] ' % dsize )
    return
```

Comment: コードの御提示ありがとうございます。とてもわかりやすくすっきりとしており
簡潔になった事がうれしいです。castも添え字の使い方もそういった記載方法があるという事がわかり大変参考になりました。

お忙しい所御回答頂き有難う御座いました！

Answer (score 0):

何か理由があって`du`コマンドを使っていたら申し訳ないのですが、pythonの機能でファイルサイズの取得はできますよ。

```
import os
size = os.stat('/var/hoge').st_size
```

上記の`size`はint型になっているので、比較なども普通にできます。

http://docs.python.jp/2.7/library/os.html#os.stat

追記
すみません、勘違いしていました。
os.statで取得できるのはあくまでファイルのサイズなので、ディレクトリの場合はファイル一覧を取得してサイズを合計する必要があります。

Comment: ディレクトリがネストしていた場合、duと同じ結果になりますか？

Comment: すみません、質問を勘違いしていました。
/var/hogeがディレクトリなのですね（というか、はっきりそう書かれていますね・・・
追記させていただきました。

Comment: duコマンドを使う理由としては、ディレクトリ内の合計サイズを手っ取り早くとれるコマンドかな？という単純な理由からでした。
os.stat.stsizeですかね。こちらの方法も知らなかったので大変参考になりました！今後ファイルに対しての扱いで重宝すると思いますので参考にさせて頂きますね。